# Is the objective of vedas spiritual prosperity or material prosperity?

Tags: vedas, india

From the pre-historic time, India is known for the spiritual prosperity. No where in the planet produced this many rishis, Yogi's, jnani's. From the material perspective we were backward. There were theories that India was the richest economy before outsiders arrive here. But still we were not able to guard our wealth. We have yajnas for creating material well beings but still we were not able to achieve the wealth that is achieved in West. Even without vedas, other countries were able to progress materially. But when it comes to inner evolution/spiritual progress, Indians are much ahead of them. In every century we are producing numerous enlightened.

Does this show that Vedas objective is spiritual growth not material growth?

Comment: The vedas show the way to both. Its up to the individual which to pursue. Traditionally one went through the four stages of life and attained material prosperity in the second stage and spiritual in the fourth stage.

Comment: Thanks swami...if the material perspective is that much effective...we could have achieved greater prosperity...or  we could have not utilized it properly...what might be the exact reason?

Comment: "From the material perspective we were backward. "  This is not true. Look at all the historical evidence. It is the west that was materially penurious. "But still we were not able to guard our wealth. "  - This is true and this happened because of slackening of our own dharmas. "Even without vedas, other countries were able to progress materially. " But look at all the corresponding damage and disharmony it created. "Does this show that Vedas objective is spiritual growth not material growth?" - No. You cannot draw that conclusion from the arguments you presented. 1/2

Comment: I fell dishormony is less today...in earlier days there were war every where happening...even within India between chozha cher and pandanus...now there is only economic war

Comment: @moonstar2001 I fell dishormony is less today...in earlier days there were war every where happening...even within India between chozha cher and pandanus...now there is only economic war

Comment: War is happening in subtler and more numerous terms (incl economic) these days, @Servent_of_Rama. There is the gross form of war also in the middle east, afghanistan, india borders etc. Take other examples like climate change. Yaagas protected ecological systems while helping in material pursuit. Now, look at the damage to the environment material prosperity has caused/continues to cause. It is safe to surmise that any non-vedic pursuit of the material or spiritual has negative side-effects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ultimate purpose of the Vedas can be understood by reading the Bhagavad Gita.

> In 15.15 Lord Krishna says:
> *sarvasya caham hrdi sannivisto
>
> mattah smrtir jnanam apohanam ca
>
> vedais ca sarvair aham eva vedyo
>
> vedanta-krd veda-vid eva caham*
>
> > Translation: 
> > I am seated in everyone's heart, and from Me come remembrance, knowledge and forgetfulness. **By all the Vedas am I to be known**; indeed I am the compiler of Vedanta, and I am the knower of the Vedas.

By reading this verse, one can very easily understand that the actual purpose of the Vedas is to understand Krishna. The Vedas primarily deal with Dharma (religiosity), Artha (Wealth), Kama (Pleasure) and Moksha (Liberation).

However, from the Bhagavad Gita we can understand that if one is following the Vedic way of life to the tee, but has still not understood that the ultimate goal is Krishna, all his endeavours are in vain.
Actually, this is the real secret teaching of the Vedas - understanding Krishna. It is very secret and hence not many people understand or realize it.

In fact Krishna himself says in the Gita (7.3):

> *manusyanam sahasresu
>
> kascid yatati siddhaye
>
> yatatam api siddhanam
>
> kascin mam vetti tattvatah*
>
> > Translation: 
> > Out of many thousands among men, one may endeavor for perfection, and of those who have achieved perfection, **hardly one** knows Me in truth.
> > And how can one know Krishna?

Krishna can only be known through devotional service, i.e., Bhakti. Knowledge, Karma, Charity, Austerity in themselves are not enough to understand, unless they are anointed with Bhakti.
So, if one somehow gets to know about this secret of the Vedas then one should take to the process of devotional service to Krishna with great faith.

Answer (score 6):

The main four objectives of Hindu way of life are

**Dharma (righteousness, morality)**

**Artha (prosperity, wealth)**

**Kama (pleasures, marital bliss etc)**

**Moksha (spiritual pursuit)**

From this, it can be understood that materialistic prosperity is not something opposed to spiritual prosperity. They both can coexist in the Vedic way of life.

Hinduism also does not preach extreme materialism like lokayata system or extreme nihilism like that of the buddhist sects. There is balance among these in the Vedic life.

This is the reason these are four important points of our lives. Righteousness is the most important value.

India was once very rich in both wealth and spirituality. But later on people started thinking wealth and power as evil and poverty as saintly.

This was reason for decline in the last 1000 years or so.

Talking about the Vedas, we find both materialistic and spiritualist subjects and hence they are not opposed to each other.

There are n number of Vedic hymns which prays for wealth, affluence, cattle, domestic pleasures, spouse, progeny, healthiness, longevity, victory, fame etc.

At the same time there are also portions which talk of spiritual progress and inward journey towards the own self.

Some of the examples of hymns for materialistic prosperity are:

> Rig Veda
>
> Sri Suktam (hymn for abundance and affluence)
>
> Atharva Veda
>
> [Hymn 17: A farmer's song and prayer to speed the plough](http://www.hinduwebsite.com/sacredscripts/hinduism/athar/avbook03.asp#av03017)
>
> [Hymn 15: A merchant's prayer for success in his business](http://www.hinduwebsite.com/sacredscripts/hinduism/athar/avbook03.asp#av03015)
>
> [Hymn 33: A prayer to Agni for protection and prosperity](http://www.hinduwebsite.com/sacredscripts/hinduism/athar/avbook04.asp#av04033)
>
> [Hymn 4: A charm against fever and other ailments](http://www.hinduwebsite.com/sacredscripts/hinduism/athar/avbook05.asp#av05004)
>
> [Hymn 17: A prayer for wealth and children](http://www.hinduwebsite.com/sacredscripts/hinduism/athar/avbook07.asp#av07017)

Same way there are verses and hymns for related to spirituality as well. If materialistic prosperity is obtained and enjoyed in a righteous way then there is nothing wrong about it.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation....we started to leave materialistic pleasure in the pursuit of spiritual success...

Comment: Yes that is the starting of downfall of India. Power and wealth are to be celebrated not to be shunned.

Answer (score 4):

> Vedah svasti.
>
> ........
>
> The Vedas confer all round bliss.
>
> **Atharva Veda 7.28.1**

And, this bliss is both material and spiritual.

> Vishve adya maruto vishva uti.
>
> .......
>
> May all the Maruts today **increase us in all ways**.
>
> ....
>
> Vishvam astu dravinam vajo asmo.
>
> ........
>
> **May all wealth and plenitude be ours**.
>
> ...........
>
> So aham vAjam saneyam agne.
>
> ........
>
> **May i win the plenitude**, O Agni.
>
> **Rig Veda 10.35.13.**

.....

> YenA sahasram vahasi yenAgne sarvavedasam.
>
> ..........
>
> O Agni, that (path) by which you bear a thousand, by which (you bear)
>   **all knowledge**, (by which you bear) **all wealth**...
>
> **Taitiriya Samhita 4.7.13.**

Note that, in the above mantra wealth and knowledge are mentioned together.

> Mayi deva dravinam AyajantAm.
>
> ..........
>
> **May the Gods bestow wealth upon me** through sacrifice.
>
> **Rig Veda 10.128**

To sum up, the idea of complete external renunciation is non-Vedic. It is never to be found in the Vedas.